# Постановка тире

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь тире или в технических текстах его можно опускать?

Дополнительное уплотнение по штоку выполнено с помощью кольца 2, которое сверху ограничено кольцом из нержавеющей стали 1, а снизу — упорным кольцом 3, через которое передается усилие сжатых, во время сборки, дисковых пружин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь тире в неполном предложении, все верно. Но слова "во время сборки" нет необходимости выделять запятыми.

Comment: Да, это я уже исправила. Спасибо.